# Search in columns of view in database

Tags: c#, sql, oracle

I have a view which I've created by joining several tables whose records can be **changed** so the content of the columns of the view can also be **changed**.
Columns of the view contain data like address,random numbers,date,some random string etc.

I'm accepting search text from user and returns rows if any of its column contain text entered by the user.

My view have millions of records so normal like query won't work(takes long time) ?
What is the most efficient way to search this view as it **changes** as its tables get **changed** ?

I'm using oracle database, C#, entityframework.

Comment: have you proper index. on the orginal tables ?

Comment: No I haven't done any indexing on original table. If I do indexing on original table and if table data get changed will my search be returning wrong data ? In order to keep my search update and accurate do I need to re-index it every time ?

Comment: I've never implemented index based search so please answer in detail

Comment: I have posted a first answer with the main suggestion ..

Comment: I have update the answer  .. hope is useful  you can find a lot of tutorial for indexes and query optimizing on google

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For better performance you should properly add index in the original table  .. these indexes are automatically refreshed by rdbms engine on each change .. so is impossible that you obtain wrong data by the index value .. the index value and the table data contain the same values..

You don't need to reindex every time ... sometimes (monthly) you can updated the related statistcs ..

so the index can change you performance in better a lot .. and this also for the view

The view in create on the top of the original table on fly and is not a stored copy of the original tables .. so the indexes help the view to render more fastly the expected  result ..

the indexes Indexes  when properly designed, serve for  important purposes in a database server:

They let the rdbms

- find groups of adjacent rows instead of single rows.
- avoid sorting by reading the rows in a desired order.
- let the server satisfy (sometimes) entire queries from the index alone, avoiding (when possible) the need to access the table at all.

from mysql https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-indexes.html

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/column-indexes.html
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/multiple-column-indexes.html

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/top-20-mysql-best-practices--net-7855

http://use-the-index-luke.com

Comment: Thanks for such good reply. I thought indexes are used only for search. Can you provide me some link which has some implemention guide/steps.

Comment: Thanks for the links.